# Get specific columns from second table after first SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having hard time trying to achieve something that seem to be simple.
I have the following query:

`SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE (condition)`

So far so good, now I have a few rows with col1,col2,col3 from table1. 
Now I also want some specific columns from another table - table2, which has a shared column = id.

Let's say I want col1, col2 from table2, where table1.id=table2.id.
I tried joins, but they always replace one of the tables and not making them together.

Example join I tried:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.col1, table2.col2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

What is the correct way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the query that you attempted with`JOIN`.

Comment: It was stuff I mixed from tutorials, I know they are meant to do a different job than what I wanted, that's why I didn't even post them, but I added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the columns aliases so they do not have the same name in the `SELECT`:

```
select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2.col1 as t2_col1
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```